# Advanced Custom Fields - display label and value only if value entered

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, echo, advanced-custom-fields

i currently have the following:

```html
<?php

$field_name = "text_field";
$field = get_field_object($field_name);   

if( isset($field['value'] ): ?> 

<table class="">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="">
            <th><?php echo $field['label']; ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $field['value']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php endif; ?>
```

my goal is to make the entire table row collapse and not display if there is no value entered.

clearly a novice. thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Wrap the `<tr></tr>` in `if( isset($field['value']) ){} `

Comment: like so (see question above)?

Comment: No, not quite. That would hide the entire table. You should put the if statement between the `<tbody>` and the `<tr>`, enclosing the row. Then the row would be hidden. On a side note, you shouldn't change your answer to reflect something I said or people can't help you with your original problem.

Comment: ok. adjusted. will test. and yes, i normally wouldn't update the question, but in this case, the problem remained the same, as did the question. just updated the code a bit. thank you.

Comment: hope this is better: <?php

$field_name = "text_field";
$field = get_field_object($field_name); ?>

<table class="">
    <tbody>
       <?php if( isset($field['value'] ): ?> 
        <tr class="">
            <th><?php echo $field['label']; ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $field['value']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

?>

Answer (score 0):

As per ACF documentation, field[‘value’] will always be set.

Instead do if (!empty($field['value']) or just if ($field['value']).

Thus it should look like this:

```
<?php
$field_name = "text_field";
$field = get_field_object($field_name);   
?>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    if ($field['value']): ?> 
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $field['label']; ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $field['value']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```